# Weird snapping - can't seem to connect the sides

Tags: snapping

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to edit an object I extracted from wow.
I have successfully extended sides and snapped points to others but when I try with these they end op floating or jumping in the opposite direction.

In the picture you can see the orange circle (where I want it to go) and the flying thing to the top left is where it ends.
Hope you can help

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: I opened a new blender, changed settings again and it works now.. but I already tried that earlier.. well ;b